# Detected java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error, which MAY be caused by incompatible Akka versions on the classpath.

Tags: akka-http

Detected java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error, which MAY be caused by incompatible Akka versions on the classpath. Please note that a given Akka version MUST be the same across all modules of Akka that you are using, e.g. if you use akka-actor [2.5.4 (resolved from current classpath)] all other core Akka modules MUST be of the same version. External projects like Alpakka, Persistence plugins or Akka HTTP etc. have their own version numbers - please make sure you're using a compatible set of libraries.

Uncaught error from thread [my-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5]: akka.actor.ActorCell.addFunctionRef(Lscala/Function2;)Lakka/actor/FunctionRef;, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for for ActorSystem[my-system]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.ActorCell.addFunctionRef(Lscala/Function2;)Lakka/actor/FunctionRef;
    at akka.stream.stage.GraphStageLogic$StageActor.(GraphStage.scala:142)
    at akka.stream.stage.GraphStageLogic.getStageActor(GraphStage.scala:956)
    at akka.stream.impl.io.ConnectionSourceStage$$anon$2.preStart(TcpStages.scala:60)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.init(GraphInterpreter.scala:520)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.init(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:380)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.tryInit(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:538)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.preStart(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:586)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundPreStart(Actor.scala:522)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundPreStart(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:529)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:591)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:462)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:484)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:282)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:223)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

Answer (score 3):

```
include transitive dependency on akka-stream
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % "10.0.10",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.5.4",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.5.4",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % "10.0.10"
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain why this answers the question.